# want to get approval status for files

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to get the status, type, and set that a document is in. I'm making the call to the `data/v1/projects/{projectId}/items/{itemId}/versions` endpoint

While looking at the UI I noticed that one of the endpoints the UI uses

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/dm/v1/projects/801f898a-4cc9-42cd-a56b-4e4b9ca0a054/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipemea%3Afs.folder%3Aco.mgQJS4w7SUOx5EbM4gVJBA/documents?entity_types=SEED_FILE&limit=200&offset=0`

contain some of the info I need

```
    {
  "urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:dm.lineage:sdpW01kQRVyGOhKFIvkELA",
  "create_time": "2021-02-01T08:42:06+0000",
  "create_user_id": "SE6ZLLDDEY9R",
  "create_user_name": "MICHAEL LEIPPER",
  "last_modified_time": "2021-02-01T08:42:07+0000",
  "last_modified_user_id": "SE6ZLLDDEY9R",
  "last_modified_user_name": "MICHAEL LEIPPER",
  "delete_by": null,
  "delete_at": null,
  "title_block_id": null,
  "title_block_image": null,
  "file_name": "happy-familyNHS (1).jpg",
  "id": "b1da56d3-5910-455c-863a-128522f9042c",
  "name": "happy-familyNHS (1).jpg",
  "description": "",
  "hidden": false,
  "move_state": null,
  "cde_is_master": null,
  "custom_attributes": [],
  "current_version": {
    "create_time": "2021-02-01T08:42:06+0000",
    "update_time": "2021-02-09T10:42:15+0000",
    "created_by": "MICHAEL LEIPPER",
    "updated_by": "MICHAEL LEIPPER",
    "create_user_name": "MICHAEL LEIPPER",
    "create_user_id": "SE6ZLLDDEY9R",
    "update_user_id": "SE6ZLLDDEY9R",
    "storage_urn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.emea.2/4b48ee2d-78fd-4e17-876c-48400c9cf6b6.jpg",
    "urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:vf.sdpW01kQRVyGOhKFIvkELA?version=1",
    "states": [
      "CONTENT_AVAILABLE"
    ],
    "name": "happy-familyNHS (1).jpg",
    "title": "happy-familyNHS (1).jpg",
    "mime_type": null,
    "revision_number": 1,
    "title_block_id": null,
    "original_name": null,
    "file_name": "happy-familyNHS (1).jpg",
    "custom_attributes": [],
    "sets": [],
    "approve_status": {
      "id": "2715ab6c-46b8-4493-b48a-426056e93cae",
      "value": "approved",
      "label": "Approved As built",
      "iconValue": "approved-check",
      "buildIn": false,
      "approverUserId": "SE6ZLLDDEY9R",
      "approverUserName": "MICHAEL LEIPPER"
    },
    "translation_states": "none",
    "translation_has_thumbnail": false,
    "forge_type": null,
    "forged_is_composite_design": null,
    "entity_type": "SEED_FILE",
    "bubble_viewable_guid": null,
    "bubble_viewable_id": null,
    "bubble_viewable_order": null,
    "bubble_viewable_resource_mimetype": null,
    "bubble_viewable_resource_urn": null,
    "bubble_urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:vf.sdpW01kQRVyGOhKFIvkELA?version=1",
    "process_state": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
    "extraction_state": "SUCCESS",
    "splitting_state": "NOT_SPLIT",
    "review_id": null,
    "review_state": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
    "review_new_document_count": null,
    "review_matched_document_count": null,
    "review_deleted": null,
    "action": null,
    "partial_extraction_failure": null,
    "move_state": null,
    "dm_command_id": "ad123f4d-04df-4620-b733-316d346856cf",
    "id": "6986e92e-7a83-4769-9101-e8a5615568c8",
    "file_size": 136688,
    "process_result": "PROCESSING_SUCCESS"
  },
  "current_set_version": 0,
  "reserved": false,
  "reserved_user_name": null,
  "reserved_user_id": null,
  "reserved_at": null,
  "latest_version": 1,
  "latest_version_file_state": [
    "CONTENT_AVAILABLE"
  ],
  "latest_version_create_time": "2021-02-01T08:42:06+0000",
  "current_version_urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:vf.sdpW01kQRVyGOhKFIvkELA?version=1",
  "latest_storage_urn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.emea.2/4b48ee2d-78fd-4e17-876c-48400c9cf6b6.jpg",
  "parent_folder_urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.folder:co.mgQJS4w7SUOx5EbM4gVJBA",
  "origin_folder_urn": null,
  "folder_set_urn": null,
  "latest_versioned_file_urn": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:vf.sdpW01kQRVyGOhKFIvkELA?version=1"
},
```

As can be seen this has approve_status in the return object. I know that this endpoint is private and not available publicly, however, is there a way to get these approval statuses for each file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for BIM 360 Docs Review and Set API. Unfortunately, there is no public API and they are still under wish:

ALEX-37150: “API wish: expose Docs Review API”

ALEX-24690: “Expose BIM 360 SET via DM API”

Sorry for the bad news.

I will add your name to the wish log above. In this context, you are interested in read access to those?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, It was only read access on those properties that my company were interested in getting from your endpoints.